# Div overlapping in Firefox

Tags: html, position

Please see the html below

it works fine in IE, but in Firefox it overlaps..please try and give me solution.
When the position of the div inside the td was given static, it's working properly.But i need absolute there since i need to use the left and top attributes.Any help is appreciated.Thanks

```
    <table style="height:auto; position:fixed;">
     <tr>
      <td style="width:210px;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;" class="contentBoxcontent">
          <div style="LEFT: 20px; WIDTH: 154px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 29px;" ><a href="#">Traffic Light</a></div>
          <div style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 161px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 33px; HEIGHT: 110px;" ><img src="../common/Images/rollingstock.png" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
          <div style="LEFT: 0px;WIDTH: 198px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 154px; HEIGHT: 66px;" ><ul><li>Traffic Light Information</li><li>Signalling Information</li><li>Euro Light</li></ul></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:210px;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;" class="contentBoxcontent">
          <div style="LEFT: 10px;WIDTH: 154px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 29px;"><a href="#">LED Dialight Iformation</a></div>
          <div style="LEFT: 0px;WIDTH: 161px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 33px; HEIGHT: 110px;"><img src="../common/Images/EN-12368_Euro.png" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
          <div style="LEFT: 0px;WIDTH: 198px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 154px; HEIGHT: 66px;"><ul><li>Traffic Light Information</li><li>Signalling Information</li><li>Caltran Signals Light</li></ul></div>
      </td>

      <td style="width:210px;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;" class="contentBoxcontent">
          <div style="LEFT: 10px;WIDTH: 154px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 29px;"><a href="#">Signalling Information</a></div>
          <div style="LEFT: 0px;WIDTH: 161px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 33px; HEIGHT: 110px;"><img src="../common/Images/caltransignals.png" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
          <div style="LEFT: 0px;WIDTH: 198px; CURSOR: move; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 154px; HEIGHT: 66px;"><ul><li>Traffic Light Information</li><li>Signalling Information Light Test Data..</li><li>LED Light</li></ul></div></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using position: relative? top and left will work with this

Comment: when i use relative, vertical space is commming in between div's

Comment: yes - because you have specified "top" rules. adjust these as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Well of course it overlaps. In every browser. You're absolute-positioning elements with exactly the same `left`​/​`top` values, how could it not? (Plus you're using `position: fixed`, which won't work in IE6, but will establish a different containing parent in other browsers.)

As Richard says, you could give each `td` element `position: relative` so that the absolutes inside are positioned relative to the cell. But if, as it looks like, all you want is three divs side-by-side, forget both absolute positioning and tables, and just say:

```
<style>
    .contentBoxcontent {
        float: left;
        width: 201px; height: 205px;
        padding: 6px; margin: 2px;
        cursor: move;
    }
    .contentBoxcontent a { margin-left: 10px; height: 29px; }
    .contentBoxcontent img { display: block; width: 161px; height: 110px; }
</style>


<div class="contentBoxcontent">
    <a href="#">Traffic light</a>
    <img src="../common/Images/rollingstock.png" alt="" />
    <ul>
        <li>Traffic light information</li>
        <li>Signalling information</li>
        <li>Euro light</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="contentBoxcontent">
    <a href="#">LED dialight information</a>
    <img src="../common/Images/EN-12368_Euro.png" alt="" />
    <ul>
        <li>Traffic light information</li>
        <li>Signalling information</li>
        <li>Caltran signals light</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="contentBoxcontent">
    <a href="#">Signalling information</a>
    <img src="../common/Images/caltransignals.png" alt="" />
    <ul>
        <li>Traffic light information</li>
        <li>Signalling information</li>
        <li>Light test data</li>
        <li>LED light</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Bobince thanks for you reply..I won't be able to change the code structure what i have provided intially since it is auto generated.I can't use the relative position height since i want to set the top based on parent table, but in relative it's not working

Comment: Argh. That's really limiting then. Still, I'm not quite sure what would ‘not work’ with making the `td`s relative-positioned... example non-working page?